# Selecting subgroups of a column - SQL (beginner)

Tags: mysql

My goal is to select genres, and count how many of each gender watch the separate genres (total). The code I have does this, but it does not display 'Male' and 'Female'. Below you can find a sample dataset and the code I have

```
Genre | Gender
-------------
Comedy| Man
Action| Woman
```

Goal

```
Genre  | Gender(M,F)
Comedy | 1M
Action | 1F


SELECT genres, COUNT(gender) AS Gender(M,F) FROM dataset
GROUP BY genres, gender
```

Comment: `SELECT genres,gender, COUNT(gender) AS Gender(M,F) FROM dataset
GROUP BY genres, gender` like this ?

Comment: @Nickname_used I cant upvote yet, but that worked! Thank you

Comment: I added the code to the answers, so you can approve it :) @Howdy626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT genres,gender, COUNT(gender) AS Gender(M,F) 
    FROM dataset 
    GROUP BY genres, gender
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32548959)

Answer (score 0):

A few things need to happen , test and transform the first character and enclose the alias, and include gender in group by

```
SELECT genre, concat(COUNT(gender),
         cast((case when left(gender,1) = 'w' then 'F' else 'M' end) as char(1))) AS 'Gender(M,F)' 
FROM t 
GROUP BY genre, gender
```